# put the output of a javascript code into file

Tags: javascript, html

hi guys i want to ask if it's posible to put the contenu of this code into file! cause when i open the source code i can't find the output there

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body onload="getLocation()">
      <p></p>
      <p id="demo"></p>
      <script>
         var x = document.getElementById("demo");
         function getLocation() {
             if (navigator.geolocation) {
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
             } else { 
                 x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
             }
         }

         function showPosition(position) {
         x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
         "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
         } 
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: i want to put the result in a file !

Comment: Then you want a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)

Answer (score 0):

use this function pass data and filename to that function it will download

```
function downloadFile(text, filename) 
{
   var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
   hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(text);
   hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
   hiddenElement.download = filename;
   hiddenElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i used it but i get this contenu in the test1.txt [object HTMLParagraphElement]

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
   hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(x);
   hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
   hiddenElement.download = 'test1.txt';
   hiddenElement.click();  

}

</script>
```